# Constructor Inheritance in D

Tags: inheritance, constructor, polymorphism, d

Is it possible to inherit constructors in D?

```
abstract class A {
    this(int a) {
        // ...
    }
}

class B: A {}

void main() {
    B b = new B(2); // Use A's constructor
}
```

I know I could just call A's constructor in B by doing `super(param)`, but there'll be a lot of classes going on so I was wondering if there is a more automated way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a language feature for it, but you can implement this as a helper mixin:

https://github.com/CyberShadow/ae/blob/29aa5dde35677a38dc8f6315dc38d7ecd437d967/utils/meta/misc.d#L219-L267

Comment: Btw does that helper work with `ref` and other qualifiers? A well-tested version of this would be really welcome in Phobos.

Comment: Hmm, it just uses `ParameterTypeTuple`, so I don't think it does. I think I implemented this when templated constructors had some issues.

Comment: seems like the link is "dead"